# Rails views based on HABTM Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

So I have this app where I'm using a HABTM association to determine "User Skills"; When a new user is created (via the *new user* view) the user can declare his/her skills via a group of **HABTM Checkboxes** available on that view with the form...

What I want to do is to have a view where I have Links based on the different skills, for example: "policemen", "doctors", "musicians" etc. And these links should point to other views where I can show to the visitor a list of *only the users* that belong to the specific category they clicked on.

My **users/skills** models (association part) look like this:

```
#User Model

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

#Skill Model

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

And (if it's helpful) my HABTM checkboxes look like this:

```
<p> What Skills do you have?

<% for skill in Skill.find(:all) %>
<div>
  <%= check_box_tag "user[skill_ids][]", skill.id, @user.skills.include?(skill) %>
  <%= skill.name %>
</div>
<% end %>
</p>
```

Let's say the skills we have are: "policeman, doctor, musician" for example... How can I create links in a view wich point to the group of users that have X skill and then with what code could I render some views that display lists with only the users that belong to X skill category?

I bet the solution is really simple... But I'm missing something obvious, maybe. Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *config/routes.rb*:

```
resources :skills
```

Generate a SkillsController with `rails g controller skills` and put there:

```
def index
  @skills = Skill.all
end

def show
  @skill = Skill.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then your views:

```
#app/views/skills/index.html.erb
<ul>
  <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
    <li><%= link_to skill.name, skill_path(skill) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

and

```
#app/views/skills/show.html.erb
<h1>Users who have the <%= @skill.name %> skill</h1>
<ul>
  <% @skill.users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.full_name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all dont use the has_and_belongs_to_many. Here is a link to RoR Guides showing how you are supposed to do the has_many :through assosiation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Secondly if you want to show your user that have 'x' skill it just the skills#show action.

```
def show
  @skill = Skill.find params[:id]
  @users = @skill.users
end
```

And on your links to view this would be something like skill_path(skill)